# EL calls remove(int i) instead of remove(Object o)

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

In my JSF page, i am trying to remove an element from a collection. Instead of calling the `Collection.remove(Object o)` method, i think the page calls `Vector.remove(int i)`.

**Update:** tagsCollection is type of `org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList`

**Update:** It gives the same exception with Vector

With the code below i get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert
>   com.question.entities.Tags[ tagId=12 ] of type class
>   com.question.entities.Tags to int

```
<ui:repeat value="#{backingBean.question.tagsCollection}" var="tag" >
    <li>
        <span>#{tag.tagTitle}</span>
        <h:commandButton>
            <f:ajax  event="click" listener="#{backingBean.question.tagsCollection.remove(tag)}"  render="@form" execute="@form"/>
        </h:commandButton>
    </li>
</ui:repeat>
```

**Update:** Here is the minimum code that can generate the exception. It throws the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert true of type class
>   java.lang.Boolean to int

**index.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="form">
            <ui:repeat value="#{backingBean.myList}" var="tag">
                #{tag.booleanValue()}
                <h:commandButton value="Delete">
                    <f:ajax listener="#{backingBean.myList.remove(tag)}"  execute="@form" render="@form"/>
                </h:commandButton>
            </ui:repeat>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**BackingBean.java**

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class BackingBean implements Serializable {

    private Collection<Boolean> myList = new Vector<Boolean>();

    public BackingBean() {
        myList.add(true);
        myList.add(false);
        myList.add(true);

    }

    public Collection<Boolean> getMyList() {
        return myList;
    }

    public void setMyList(Collection<Boolean> myList) {
        this.myList = myList;
    }

}
```

Comment: It is a  "Tags" object.

Comment: Which remove methods are available to you when you type the dot after `tagsCollection` ?

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan Only remove(Object o) is available.

Comment: Very interesting.

I've tried yesterday in my personal laptop with JDK 8 and had the same problem you describe.

Now, I've tried it with jdk1.7.0_45 and GF 4.0.0 build 89 and works ok.

may be it's a jvm problem?

Comment: @Salih any reason why you are casting the Collection into Vector then back to Collection in the getter ? Anyway, the workaround I have posted works..can you confirm ?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't know how JSF handles this in the background, but to avoid it just call your own bean method that does the same

```
<f:ajax  event="click" listener="#{backingBean.removeTag(backingBean.question, tag)}"  render="@form" execute="@form"/>

public void removeTag(Question question, Tag tag) {
    question.getTagsCollection().remove(tag);
}
```

Comment: I already know, i can do that with a backing bean method. I want to do it directly without extra method.

Comment: @SalihErikci What type is `tagsCollection`?

Comment: I don't know what type it is exactly. It is instantiated by JPA. It is defined as private Collection<Tags> tagsCollection;

Comment: @SalihErikci you should know the type of `tagsCollection`. Make sure to declare it as a `List` (despite the kind of `Collection` implementation it uses behind the scenes)

Comment: Why should I know? I know it is a collection. (It is declared so.) It should call the right remove() method. Does it matter whether it is List or Set?

Comment: @SalihErikci it's like you don't know what you're developing... And yes, depending on your JSF version, it matters.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you please explain why the implementation detail really matters. In my application it doesn't matter for me whether the implementation is Set or List. I just use the add() and remove() methods which are the methods of the Collection interface. Isn't this the purpose of the Interfaces? It is clear that this is a bug of JSF. I don't understand why you think that "I don't know what I am developing"